# moving joomla site from windows to linux servers

Tags: asp.net, linux, xampp, hosting, joomla3.0

Would there be a problem if I host my joomla site created in xampp for windows on linux servers? If so, what can be done? Also, is there a way to create linux environment(at least for the sake of running xampp) on windows 7 to create joomla sites which should have no problem running on linux servers?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any problems

Answer (score 1):

You could install Linux on Windows PC and to create a multi boot.
My advice is to get some Linux hosting providing money back guarantee, to move your site and if this is not OK to cancel the service and get your money back.
You should not have any problems to move your site because joomla is based on PHP. The problems will be if it was on ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If URL rewriting is enabled, you will need to create a .htaccess file to replace your web.config file.

You will also need to update your tmp and log paths in Global Configuration.

Apart from the above, there will likely be no other issues.

An alternative to dual boot is to use virtualisation software such as VirtualBox so you can run Linux on your Windows PC. This works well as long as you have enough memory available.

VirtualBox is free: https://www.virtualbox.org